# How to open iframe scr area in parent window

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I have a web page including an iframe. The src of the iframe is a html-document generated through vba-code out of an excel-table. The generated html document includes hyperlinks as `<area>` and I want the hyperlinks open in a new window (`_blank`).

How can I do this? Is it possible to write a javascript code to get the content of the iframe src and add to every `<area>`-Tag the attribute `target="_blank"`?

I'd tried to modify the html code. but its not possible to read the generated html code again in vba to modify it and generate it again.

I already added `<base target="_blank/>` at the beginning of the generated html code (= src of iframe), but that's not the way it should work. It should be automatically added as target.

```
Sub GO_to_HTML()
    Dim currentWorkbook As String
    Dim currentWorkbookDir As String
    Dim Tabelle_save As String

    currentWorkbook = documentname 'ActiveWorkbook.Name
    currentWorkbookDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    ChDir currentWorkbookDir
    pfad = ActiveWorkbook.Path & dateiname

'HTML

   ActiveWorkbook.Save

     With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
        dateiname & ".htm" _
        , "GO", "$A1:$F30", xlHtmlStatic, "document1234", "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False

    End With
End Sub
```